# Mean value theorem of integrals

Tags: calculus, integration

> Let $f: [1, 2] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be an integrable function. Let $\bar{f} \in \mathbb{R}$ be the mean of the integral. So $$\bar{f} = \frac{1}{b-a} \int_{a}^{b} f(t) dt$$
>
> Show that $$\int_{a}^{b} (f(x)-\bar{f}) dx = 0$$

How should one approach this? I know from the Fundamental theorem of calculus that we can express $\frac{1}{b-a} \int_{a}^{b} f(t) dt$ as $\frac{F(b)-F(a)}{b-a}$, but does that help us here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$\int_a^b(f(x)-\overline{f})\mathrm{d}x = \int_a^bf(x)\mathrm{d}x-\int_a^b\overline{f}\mathrm{d}x$$
$$ = (b-a)\overline{f}-\overline{f}(b-a)$$
$$=0$$

Comment: Sorry i meant how do we get $\int_a^b\overline{f}\mathrm{d}x = \overline{f}(b-a)$

Comment: @Nate, $\overline f$ is a constant and therefore, it comes out of integration.

Comment: So essentially $\int_a^b\mathrm{d}x = (b-a)$

Comment: @Nate, Yes, that is what we are using.

Answer (score 1):

Note that, as you wrote
$$\bar f=\frac1{b-a}\int_a^b f(x)dx=\frac{F(b)-F(a)}{b-a}$$
So $\bar f$ is a constant, then
$$\int_a^b\left(f(x)-\bar f\right)dx$$
$$\int_a^b f(x)dx -\int_a^b\bar fdx$$
$$\int_a^b f(x)dx -\int_a^b\frac{F(b)-F(a)}{b-a}dx$$
$$\int_a^b f(x)dx -\frac{F(b)-F(a)}{b-a}\int_a^b dx$$
$$(F(b)-F(a)) -\frac{F(b)-F(a)}{b-a}(b-a)$$
$$(F(b)-F(a)) -(F(b)-F(a))$$
$$0$$